# Android Studio - ¿Como usar el método onBackPressed entre fragments? (Navigation Drawer)

Tags: android, android-fragment, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

**Descripción:**

La navegación dentro de mi app se da por el navigation drawer, el cual está dentro de MainActivity. Cada sección de mi aplicación es un fragment que está dentro de la misma **MainActivity** a los cuales se puede acceder únicamente desde el Drawer Layout.

**Pregunta:**

Sabiendo lo anterior: ¿Como puedo hacer para volver hacia el fragment previo al que estoy situado ahora mediante un botón dentro de cada fragment?

**Supongamos** que estoy en *Fragment A* y paso a *Fragment C* y luego a *Fragment D* **(Todos dentro de MainActivity)**

¿Como puedo hacer para que, tocando un botón (Al cual llamaré "Botón  Back") pueda volver desde *Fragment D* hacia *Fragment C* y luego, dentro de *Fragment C*, volver con un nuevo "Botón Back" hacia *Fragment A*.

**Edit:**

**Código XML de mi MainActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<!--APP_BAR_MAIN-->
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/text_color_nav_item_selected"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/letraNav"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Código XML de APP BAR MAIN**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ui.MainActivity"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<!--CONTENT MAIN-->
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Código XML de CONTENT MAIN:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Agradezco mucho su lectura!**

Comment: Probaste con los métodos de [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui#Replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en mi caso lo hice en kotlin el onbackpressed en fragment mediante (Navigation Drawer) , en el caso tengas un botón  debes ingresar el siguiente codigo dentro del botón:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Regresara al fragment anterior al cual hallas entrado (La funcionalidad normal del onbackpressed).

Comment: Super simple. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente debes realizar una transaccion de Fragments dependiendo del caso, usando la clase [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Debes tener en tu `MainActivity` un layout que contenga un "contenedor" que seria un `FragmentLayout`, en el cual realizarias las transacciones cambiando el fragmento deseado, ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

"desde Fragment D hacia Fragment C", suponiendo que cargaste el Fragment D al dar clic en el boton, cambiarias a Fragment C:

```
    Button btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

                  fragment = new FragmentC();                   

                    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();

    });
```

"y luego, dentro de Fragment C, volver con un nuevo "Botón Back" hacia Fragment A", suponiendo que cargaste el Fragment C al dar clic en el boton, cambiarias a Fragment A:

```
    Button btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

                  fragment = new FragmentA();                   

                    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();

    });
```

Comment: Super clara tu respuesta, pero creo deberte una disculpa por no haber adjuntado el código de mi Main Activity. Actualizé la pregunta...